# stbi_image_write Изменить размер изображения

Tags: c++, png, обработка-изображений

подскажите пожалуйста как изменить размер изображения ?
загружаю картинку через функцию stbi_load и сохраняю через stbi_write_png
нужно создать прозрачную картинку размером 120х120 и по центре вставить то, что загрузил через stbi_load.
подскажите как сделать